# How to Iterate Through Values in Properties File in Java

Tags: java, properties, iterator, arraylist, csv

so I was wondering if anyone knew how I would go about reading in mutliple values from a key, delimiting them by commas and storing them to an arraylist from a properties file in java?

---

**I have a properties file with just this in it:**

> currentProposalsLocation = C:/Documents and Settings/Intern
>   Project/Extracted Items
>   keywordsList = "A,B,C,D,E,F"

---

**And this is my code to load the properties file:**

```
    static String proposalsDirectory;
    static ArrayList<String> keywordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static final String PROP_FILE="C:/Documents and Settings/Intern Project/ipConfig.properties";

public static void readPropertiesFile()
{
     try
    {
         InputStream is = XMLTagParser.class.getResourceAsStream(PROP_FILE);
         Properties prop = new Properties();
         prop.load(is);
         proposalsDirectory = prop.getProperty("currentProposalsLocation");
         //?????What to do here????
         is.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println("Failed to read from " + PROP_FILE + " file.");
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: could you provide sample imput file and describe demanded otput?

Comment: @zacheusz The two lines above my code are what's in the input file. And the expected output is exactly as I noted originally: just an arraylist with all the values stored in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
keywordsList.addAll(Arrays.asList(prop.getProperty("keywordsList").split(","));
```

Should work.

Answer (score 3):

`Properties` extends `HashTable` implements `Map`, so you can get all the keys as a `Set<String>` using `keySet()`.

Any property value is a String.  You can split the String given a delimiter.

If you're asking how to add that Object back into the Properties, the answer is "you can't".  Properties uses a String key and a String value.  If you want multi-map behavior (String key, List value), you'll have to implement your own.

Comment: wait is this SO about iterating over keys or getting each comma separated value? haha

Comment: Question could be interpreted as asking both.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [Enumerator](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/UsingEnumerationtoloopthroughProperties.htm) to cycle through `Properties`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another option, you could set the properties up in an XML file, use [Spring Dependency Injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html) to load them into an object within your java code, and then manipulate them however you please.

Note with Dependency Injection, you could set that list up directly in the XML as a List so you wouldn't even have to do all the busy work of turning a comma separated String into a List.